Clarification on getting 1 Hz from a 32.768 kHz input using 74HC4060BQ-Q100
I'm working on a project where I need to divide a 32.768 kHz signal down to 1 Hz. I initially thought I needed a Q14 output from a counter, similar to the CD4060 circuit where Q14 is passed to a D flip-flop to achieve 1 Hz.
I'm using the Nexperia 74HC4060BQ-Q100, a 14-stage binary ripple counter. The datasheet states it has ten buffered parallel outputs labeled Q3 to Q9 and Q11 to Q13. Here's where I'm getting confused:

Since the counter only goes up to Q13, does Q13 represent the 14th stage and thus divide the frequency by 2^14?
If Q13 gives a 2 Hz output from the 32.768 kHz input, can I simply add an additional D flip-flop to divide this by 2 again to achieve the 1 Hz frequency I need?
Are there any specific considerations or potential issues I should watch out for when implementing this setup?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or confirmation on this. Thank you!
Datasheet:

74HC4060BQ-Q100 Datasheet


Yes, you're right. Specifically:

Yes, fQ13 is fCP ÷ 16384 (i.e. 2^14).
Yes, a D-type Flip-Flop (DFF) can be used for the final halving of fQ13 (1 Hz) to 1 .
Nothing in particular. Follow the Typical Crystal Oscillator circuit and component value guidelines in the 74HC4060 datasheet, they're reliable.


Thank you for your help. Also, should CTC be left floating when arranged in the typical crystal oscillator circuit?

Yes, you leave it open.
